# Exchange 2007 error: Could not find any Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007

I am having a terrible time trying to install Exchange 2007 on Windows Server 2008.

The latest error I am receiving during the install process is:

```
Summary: 3 item(s). 0 succeeded, 3 failed. 
Elapsed time: 00:00:10


Hub Transport Role Prerequisites
Failed

Error:
Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: 
Could not find any Domain Controller in domain mydomain.com.au.

Elapsed Time: 00:00:07


Client Access Role Prerequisites
Failed

Error:
Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: 
Could not find any Domain Controller in domain mydomain.com.au.

Elapsed Time: 00:00:01


Mailbox Role Prerequisites
Failed

Error:
Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: 
Could not find any Domain Controller in domain mydomain.com.au.

Warning:
If Outlook Web Access is in use, you should replicate the free/busy folder 
on this server to every other free/busy server in the organization. 
This step should be performed once Setup completes.

Elapsed Time: 00:00:01
```

Does anyone have good experience they can share with deploying Exchange 2007 on Server 2008?

Comment: Event Viewer shows.... The description for Event ID 2152 from source MSExchange ADAccess cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the server you're trying to install Exchange on has some troubles accessing Active Directory. The Exchange setup log is of very little help here, you should check if your AD domain is operating correctly and if the server is able to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This server joined the domain ok (Server 2003 DC), and nslookup resolves ok too.